# Google Maps vs. ggplot2/MarMap

Tags: r, google-maps, dictionary, ggplot2

Below is a JavaScript page I have created that allows me add and freely move markers on the map. From this map I can figure out the regions I am interested in.

Basically what I want to do is show the same map using `ggplot2/MarMap` with coastline indicators + bathymetry data. I am really just interested in getting bathymetry data per GPS location, basically getting negative/positive elevation per Lat+Long, so I was thinking if I can plot it then I should be able to export data to a Database. I am also interested in coastline data, so I want to know how close I am (Lat/Long) to coastline, so with plot data I was also going to augment in DB.

[image]

Here is the R script that I am using:

```
library(marmap);
library(ggplot2);

a_lon1 = -79.89836596313478;
a_lon2 = -79.97179329675288;

a_lat1 = 32.76506070891712;
a_lat2 = 32.803624214389615;

dat <- getNOAA.bathy(a_lon1,a_lon2,a_lat1,a_lat2, keep=FALSE);    

autoplot(dat, geom=c("r", "c"), colour="white", size=0.1) + scale_fill_etopo();
```

Here is the output of above R script:

[image]

### Questions:

- Why do both images not match?
- In google-maps I am using zoom value 13. How does that translate in ggplot2/MarMap?
- Is it possible to zoom in ggplot2/MarMap into a (Lat/Long)-(Lat/Long) region?
- Is it possible to plot what I am asking for?

Comment: Did you check the object `dat`? It clearly is a larger target area than google maps. Also the default resolution for the grid is 4 minutes by 4 minutes, which is larger than the area you're asking for in the first place.

Comment: Why not just use NOAA's viewer? https://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/viewers/bathymetry/

Comment: It is okay to get more data than I want as long as it includes my region. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you got this result. When I use your script, I get an error since the area your are trying to fetch from the ETOPO1 database using `getNOAA.bathy()` is too small. However, adding `resolution=1` (this gives the highest possible resolution for the ETOPO1 database), here is what I get:

[image]

To answer your questions:

- *Why do both images not match?* 
  Probably because `getNOAA.bathy()` returned an error and the object `dat` you're using has been created before, using another set of coordinates
- *In google-maps I am using zoom value 13. How does that translate in ggplot2/MarMap?*
  I have no clue!
- *Is it possible to zoom in ggplot2/MarMap into a (Lat/Long)-(Lat/Long) region?*
  I urge you to take a look at section 4 of the `marmap-DataAnalysis` vignette. This section is dedicated to working with big files. You will find there that you can zoom in any area of a `bathy` object by using (for instance) the `subsetBathy()` function that will allow you to click on a map to define the desired area
- *Is it possible to plot what I am asking for?* Yes, but it would be much easier to use base graphics and not ggplot2. Once again, you should read the package vignettes.

Finally, regarding the coastline data, you can use the `dist2isobath()` function to compute the distance between any gps point and any isobath, including the coastline. Guess where you can learn more about this function and how to use it...